# Comparing two tables for similar values and Inserting values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on databases and now I need some advice's from you guys..
I have 2 Tables with many rows and columns and these db's contain addresses of customers. Names of the tables are Data, Orders.

Now the problem is I have to search the addresses present in Table Orders with the addresses in Data using email as the criteria.
If there is a match in emails then its ok....or else we should insert the addresses of the table Orders in table Data. ...

I made this query but i am getting some error.

```
INSERT INTO orders (orders_id, customers_id, customers_cid, customers_vat_id, customers_name, customers_email_address) VALUES( (select o.* from Test.dbo.orders o where o.customers_email_address not in ( select a.email0 from CobraDemoData.dbo.Data a)))
```

Any help is much appreciated..
Thanks,
subash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the values directly from a select statement--don't use `values` when you want to do that. Additionally, you can use `not exists` in lieu of `not in`, as SQL Server usually runs that much faster, but it's case-by-case, so you can look at the query plan if it's really an issue.

```
insert into orders (orders_id, customers_id, customers_cid, customers_vat_id, customers_name, customers_email_address)
select
    o.*
from
    Test.dbo.orders o
where
    not exists (
        select 1
        from
            CobraDemoData.dbo.Data a
        where
            a.email0 = o.customers_email_address
    )
```

Also, you probably want to specify the columns in the select statement, just to make sure the right columns are transposed.